# excluding all documents that have indexed in a particular field elements that are not part of a given set

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

In my Lucene search I want to exclude all documents that have indexed in a particular field elements that are not part of a given set.

For example, lets say my document represents a drawing. and has a color field. In the color field I index all the colors that are used in a drawing. Now say I have access to say five colors. red, blue, green, purple, and brown.  I want to only retrieve drawings that use these colors and any drawing that has a color not in the colors mentioned above should be excluded. If I want all drawings that use all these colors and nothing but all these colors, I can add a new field to my document for 'number of colors' and then build my Boolean query by adding MUST term queries for each of the colors and also adding a MUST Boolean query with the count as the number of colors. But I want to also retrieve all documents that have any combination of the 5 colors mentioned above. So a drawing that is done entirely with brown would also be retrieved.

Please note that I have thousands of colors. So creating a field for each color and then doing a MUST_NOT for everyone other than my 5 colors would also not be an option.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are built-in ways of doing that. Instead, you want to store the set of colors (that a particular drawing contains) somewhere. Then, as you go through each search result at search-time, you load the color set, check if it contains any of the "other" colors, and filter the result accordingly.

That somewhere can be any of at least two places:

- Stored field: For example, you can store the color set as a comma-delimited list of color names as a String.
- Term vector: If you index the color field with term vectors, then at search-time, you can call [IndexReader.getTermFreqVector(int, String)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the term vector information of that document/field. The resulting TermFreqVector object gives you a list (actually a set) of terms (i.e. colors in your case) in that field.

Comment: Thanks! So lets say that I store all the colors used in a drawing in a field using one of the two ways you indicated.  I still need to retrieve all documents from Lucene (an expensive operation) and then iterate through those checking on each color in the drawing to make sure it belongs to my collection of colors.  So I will not be really using the built in muscle of Lucene? Am I correct or did I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to retrieve all documents, just the ones you narrow down to in previous steps (i.e. documents having at least one of the mentioned colors). Even for these documents, for filtering purpose, you only need to retrieving the color field, which is probably much smaller then the "main" text field. Lucene lets you select which field(s) to retrieve with FieldSelector. Also, you can still use text search, scoring, sorting, etc. provided by Lucene. You are just doing some custom filtering on top of what Lucene provides.